# how to install templates in django? I connected the template to the views file and in the settings file. then i used render to display the template

Tags: python, django

I connected the template to the views file and in the settings file. then i used render to display the template

```
def index(request):
   return render(request, 'pages/pages.html')
```

and in the settings file I set it through the `os` library

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
```

But I am still getting an error "template does not exist" while I'm very sure I typed the right path and imported the views file in the urls file and everything is fine just that template doesn't load.
anyone knows what could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: Show your file tree.

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.py` file make sure the `TEMPLATES` section has `'APP_DIRS'` set to True (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-APP_DIRS).

In your pages app you'll want a tree structure like:

```
/pages
 |- templates
    |- pages
       |- pages.html
 admin.py
 models.py
 views.py
```

This should allow you then to use the pages name space to specify your html files. There are other options, but this is the one I **think** may be the most common.

See https://learndjango.com/tutorials/template-structure for others.

Comment: good to hear! if you have the ability, please mark the answer as accepted so others know it has been answered.